# Call Github Actions in CookieCutter template

Tags: python, github, github-actions, cookiecutter

I am building a template repo that uses [CookieCutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter). The template itself will contain github action files that execute the tests in the template.

When I make changes to the template itself, in the PR, I want to instantiate the template with the default options and then call the github action files in the template to test the template itself.

What I have working now is I instantiate the template and then use Tox and Pytest to run the tests directly.  This works but I would like to call the template action files in order to test the CICD of the template itself.

Is this possible?

TIA!

Comment: You could have your code push the templated output to a separate repo's branch and have that separate repo configured to run actions. The actions in your main repo could use github api's to query the state of the workflow running in the other repos branch and report the final success/failure.